# C++11 function static variable initialization weirdness

Tags: multithreading, c++11, clang, libc++

I have plain simple function that maps some HTTP status codes to strings:

```
const std::string & status_name(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}
```

One day, on our test servers, a crash has occurred. Analysing core dump is seems that `std::out_of_range` exception was thrown in `status_table.at(0);`. Another weird thing is that status code in question was `200`. Program that crashed abuses multiple threads, so my stomach feel tells me that this issue is thread-related.

I'm really puzzled about how it's even possible. It's **C++11** and this version of standard provides guarantees regarding thread-safety of static variable initialization. The compiler is **clang-3.3**, architecture is x64 and CPU is *Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5506*.

The only two things come to mind:

1. there's some bug in the code I miss to see;
2. this weirdness is related to CPU cache incoherency: thread that caused crash saw guard variable as indicating 'initialized' state of
   `status_table` but object itself was seen empty.

**Update on the issue:**

After making a small test case I was able to easily reproduce the problem:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

const std::string & status_name1(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name2(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name3(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name4(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name5(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name6(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name7(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

const std::string & status_name8(int code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> status_table {
        { 0, "UNKNOWN" },
        { 100, "Continue" },
        { 101, "Switching Protocols" },
        { 200, "OK" },
        { 201, "Created" },
        { 202, "Accepted" },
        { 203, "Non-Authoritative Information" },
        { 204, "No Content" },
        { 205, "Reset Content" },
        { 206, "Partial Content" },
        { 300, "Multiple Choices" },
        { 301, "Moved Permanently" },
        { 302, "Found" },
        { 303, "See Other" },
        { 304, "Not Modified" },
        { 305, "Use Proxy" },
        { 307, "Temporary Redirect" },
        { 400, "Bad Request" },
        { 401, "Unauthorized" },
        { 402, "Payment Required" },
        { 403, "Forbidden" },
        { 404, "Not Found" },
        { 405, "Method Not Allowed" },
        { 406, "Not Acceptable" },
        { 407, "Proxy Authentication Required" },
        { 408, "Request Timeout" },
        { 409, "Conflict" },
        { 410, "Gone" },
        { 411, "Length Required" },
        { 412, "Precondition Failed" },
        { 413, "Request Entity Too Large" },
        { 414, "Request-URI Too Long" },
        { 415, "Unsupported Media Type" },
        { 416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" },
        { 417, "Expectation Failed" },
        { 499, "Rotten session" },
        { 500, "Internal Server Error" },
        { 501, "Not Implemented" },
        { 502, "Bad Gateway" },
        { 503, "Service Unavailable" },
        { 504, "Gateway Timeout" },
        { 505, "HTTP Version Not Supported" },
    };

    auto it = status_table.find(code);

    if (it != status_table.end())
        return it->second;

    return status_table.at(0);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_pool;
    auto guard_variable = std::make_shared<std::atomic<int>>(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        thread_pool.push_back(std::thread([guard_variable] {
            while (!guard_variable->load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                /// Noop.
            }

            int i = 0;
            i += status_name1(200).length();
            i += status_name2(200).length();
            i += status_name3(200).length();
            i += status_name4(200).length();
            i += status_name5(200).length();
            i += status_name6(200).length();
            i += status_name7(200).length();
            i += status_name8(200).length();
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }));
    }

    usleep(50000);
    guard_variable->store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    for (auto && thread : thread_pool) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works as expected everywhere else other than on that test machine. No matter what version of **clang** I use (3.3, 3.6) this test program crashes due to exception immediately, at different times in different `status_name*` function.

What can possibly cause this behaviour? Is CPU cache inconsistency or is it bug in **libc++**?

Comment: @JohnZwinck see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at

Comment: You should use `const char*` as the mapped type instead of `std::string`.  It's much more efficient since you're storing literals anyway.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I totally missed all your points... I use `std::string` because I want `const std::string &` as a result of function call, ie collection of 'static' strings.

Comment: Why not return `const char*` from the function?  It's valid to return a pointer to a literal "C" string.  By the way, storing the whole mess of pairs in a sorted vector would be more efficient in both space and time than an unordered_map.

Comment: It could be a bug in the compiler. Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Maybe because It's C++ and I need `std::string` (as I stated previously). And also, lookup by hash table is best trade-off memory-wise and speed-wise, comparing to other approaches (map, sorted array, vector with holes).

Comment: @GreenScape: Lookup by hash table *for this particular data set* is going to be slower and more space-consuming than using a sorted vector.  But hey, it's up to you!  Hash tables are faster in theory, but not always in practice.

Comment: @n.m. Weirdly, I can't reproduce this in production, where there are dozens of servers and each server has ~ x20000 more load. It is hard to reproduce on test server because there is no much load and it's hard to synchronise two thread. Next step for me is to make a test case...

Comment: May be you can look into generated assembly? It will be easy to see if there is a proper mutex around static initialization or not.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but I'd suspect there might be a defect in `unordered_map::find`. The library is supposed to provide a guarantee that all calls to `find()` are independent, but they might not be. If there's anything like memoized results or some such shared data and the appropriate memory fences aren't in place there could be corruption on certain results.

Comment: @SergeyA I see there `__cxa_guard_acquire`, `__cxa_guard_release` and `__cxa_guard_abort`, so yeah probably that's the mutex

Comment: @eh9, it's **very** unlikely that the libc++ developers made that mistake.

Comment: @GreenScape, does it make any difference if you make the map `const`? I agree with the comment above that a sorted vector searched with `std::lower_bound` will be faster for this use case (and will also avoid a second lookup for the "UNKNOWN" case because that will be simply `status_table.front()`). Also why is your `guard_variable` in the test case using a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck `const` does not make any difference. It does not matter whether it is `shared_ptr` or not. I don't like taking reference to stack of other thread.

Comment: The test case does not (can not) compile.

Comment: @HowardHinnant it was a copy-paste issue. Fixed now, Sorry.

Comment: @GreenScape Hi I ran across this similar issue recently and couldn't figure it out. My code is almost same as yours, except we use `count()` instead of `find()`. May I ask what eventually had you done on this issue? Maybe helpful on my issue too.

Comment: @GreenScape FYI: we use gcc-10 on almalinux-8 and the code is compiled in O2

Comment: @KingsleyChen, believe it or not: time. Hopefully for us, it was a test machine. We've just upgraded our FreeBSD version, which lead to a newer version of clang/libc++ and the issue faded away. Most likely, it was an issue in **libc++**.

Answer (score 1):

Clang supports "magic statics" (N2660 **Dynamic initialization and destruction with concurrency**) since 2.9 per http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html.

Rather than a bug in the compiler or your immediate code, it is more likely that a bug elsewhere in your code is corrupting program state, causing `status_table` to appear initialized but empty.

Comment: In the code dump it is initialized, with the all elements inside. Of course, there's a window between iterator comparison and exception propagation, but how likely is it?

Comment: Test case attached in update discards this conclusion, unfortunately. In there I have isolated piece of code in question.

Comment: @GreenScape if it occurs only on a particular machine, it's possible that that machine has a bad libstdc++ (which provides `__cxa_guard_acquire` etc.)